# Creating a migration with two columns referencing the same table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called `Teams` and I am creating a table called `Games`... I'm getting a little mixed up writing the migration for `Games`.

Ideally I want there to be a `home_team` column and a `away_team` column. Both columns will use a foreign key referencing the the `id` column in the `Teams` table.

```
          TEAMS TABLE
| id  | home_team | away_team |
| --- | ----------| --------- |
|  1  |     2     |     5     |
|  2  |     1     |     3     |
|  3  |     4     |     6     |
```

Would using `t.references` be suitable for this? Below is what I have so far... not sure if this is what I want.

```
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.references :home_team, references: teams
      t.references :away_team, references: teams
    end
```

Will I also need to add belongs_to to the `team model`?

Comment: No. Your  migration will add it for you.. try and see. But yes `belongs_to` in the model is needed. :)

Comment: Again, when you will write the belongs to in the model you need to take extra care, as the F-keys are here can't be driven from the model names, as they are something different from the Rails conventions. So you need to mention them explicitly in your `has_many` declarations models.